# since when CentOS has a welcome page with the default http server

Tags: linux, centos, webserver, http

On my network, I have many CentOS VMs with various versions dating from very recently to 10-15 years ago. For some of them I don't have credentials but I want to check if I should keep them by the install date \ release date of the OS.

I've noticed some have a centos welcome page when using the IP or domain with port 80 (see example below), I want to skim over the servers and check which ones to spend time on and check for relevance, and which ones can be deleted and returned to the resource pool.

[image: welcome page example screenshot]

Now, my question is, when did the welcome page first appear (if not from the start (i.e. 2004 according to Wikipedia))? was it changed over the years?  and if so, how can I match the style or text to each version?

Comment: Are you using nginx? I removed this application and the Welcome page is not not available.

Comment: I can see that some webserver is installed but I can't login (which would render the need to look at the webpage useless if I can login)